# Deleted files from /etc/exim4

Tags: ubuntu, email, configuration, exim

I installed Exim4. But then I deleted it and purged it. Now a I want to reinstall it, but all config files are gone (in /etc/exim4). Can I recorver them?

Comment: Retrieve them from your backups?

Answer (score 0):

Some rpm based distros save config files when removing packages by naming them something like app.config.rpmsave. I don't know where Ubuntu puts them, but if they were saved they are probably sitting around somewhere obvious. Do a search by partial file name and see what you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have backups, you will have lost what was there.  If you made any additions to the split configuration, I would expect them to have been left behind.  All of the standard configuration files will be created if you reinstall.  This includes the `update-exim.conf.conf` file which is where most of the configuration is normally done.

There are a few tools which monitor changes to `/etc`.  The keep a copy of the directory to do the comparisons against. None of them are installed by default.  If you had one of them installed I would expect you would have been notified of the change.

Comment: If he removed the package, the config files are kept; once the package is purged, the config files are deleted.

Comment: @Steven: Correct, but it was stated that the package was purged.  This will result in the conffiles being deleted.  Conffiles are listed in the package's `.conffiles` file in the `/var/lib/dpkg/info` directory.  Files the user added are kept as the are not listed, and the corresponding directories are kept because they are not empty.